# Residual sum of squares equals zero with no error code

Tags: r, anova, residuals

Why are the values for sums of squares the same for `A`, `B` and `F` across all models despite having different model structure? Why are the residual sum of squares zero?

I recognize that `res` was simulated to depend on `A`, `B` and their interaction term `A*B` and the F is a correlated variable with A, But I cannot make sense of sum of squares residuals = 0 or why the sum of squares do not change for the fixed variables.

## Simulated Data

```
alpha = 1
beta1 = 2
beta2 = -1
beta3 = -2
set.seed(786)
A = c(rep(c(0), 500), rep(c(1), 500)) 
B = rep(c(rep(c(0), 250), rep(c(1), 250)), 2) 
e = rnorm(1000, 10, sd=2)  
res = alpha + beta1*A + beta2*B + beta3*A*B + e 
z_res= (res - mean(res)) / sd(res)
F <- ifelse(A==0, res+2 , res-2) 
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,F, z_res))
```

## Various models

```
mod <- aov(z_res ~ A + B+ F, data=dat)
summary(mod)

mod<-aov(z_res ~ A + B + A*B+ A*F, data=dat)
summary(mod)

mod<-aov(z_res ~ A + B +A*F, data=dat)
summary(mod)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you can exactly predict the value of *z_res* from *A* and *F* alone, because you define

```
z_res= (res - mean(res)) / sd(res)
F <- ifelse(A==0, res+2 , res-2)
```

The corresponding model `z_res ~ A + F` gives $R^2=1$ and thus a prefect fit, as it should be. For convenience, let `z := z_res` and `y := res`. Then you have defined:
$$z = \frac{y-c}{d} \quad\mbox{and}\quad F = y + 2 - 4\cdot A$$
It follows that
$$z = \frac{F -2 + 4\cdot A -c}{d}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 F + \beta_2 A$$

Comment: It is not clear to me why those definitions lead to all the variation in `z_res` being accounted for by `A` and `F`. I realize that may be obvious to others but I am not seeing it. If `res = alpha + beta1*A + beta2*B + beta3*A*B + e` and `z_res` is the standardized version of that, why do `F` and `A` account for all the variation in `z_res` if `F` was never in the model for `res`? I would have expected a model with `A*B` to account for more variation in `z_res` since that was in the model for `res`.

Comment: @WabiSabi I have edited my answer and written down the formula that your code defines. As you are a new contributor, here is a hint: if a question is resolved, do not forget to accept the answer so that the question no longer appears in the unanswered questions.